# Showing a hidden WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

### In a WPF window I want to hide it, show another window using `ShowDialog` then unhide the first window.

---

When I do that:

```
this.Hide();
var window2 = new Window2();
window2.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

The first window open as a blank and empty window.

What's wrong in this technique?

---

When I do that:

```
var window2 = new Window2();
Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
window2.ShowDialog();
Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

The first window exits then the application.

What's wrong in this technique too?

Comment: use this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden to hide and this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible to show it back.

Comment: what is that new Window2().. I doubt that should be new Window()???

Comment: @Kaushik Yes it's a new window

Comment: @Kaushik: Window2 is class name here.

Comment: I have replicated what code you have posted and am having no errors. I dont think the code is the problem

Comment: @Nitesh the Visibility doesn't work. the first window exit as             this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; doesn't exist.

Comment: So, Are you sure `this` is currently the first window?

Comment: @MSA: What do you mean by doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;    
...    
this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Also, I saw your comment above that this doesn't work. However, I started a new WPF project, did this, built and ran it. It works.

Note that there are no errors.

[image]

Comment: Why shouldn't Hide be used? Note that `Show` and `Hide` actually do set Visibility to `Visible` and `Hidden`. The only difference is that they are synchronous, i.e. they will not return until the window has actually updated. Since he is using `ShowDialog`, synchronous behavior is probably preferred.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Window2 window2  = new Window2();
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        window2.ShowDialog();
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case next code worked out:

```
new HiddenWindow
    {
       WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
       AllowsTransparency = true,
       Opacity = 0.0
     }.Show();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (Window window in App.Current.Windows)

        {
            if (!window.IsActive)
            {
                window.Show();
            }
        }
```

Works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Check your `Application.Current.ShutdownMode`. Closing the window you assign to `Application.Current.MainWindow` will cause the application to shutdown, if `Application.Current.ShutdownMode` is set to `OnMainWindowClose`. In your case I would set it to `OnExplicitShutdown`. You can see the default values being set in `app.xaml` of your WPF application project.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me to solve the issue of opening multiple dialogs after each other with .ShowDialog. Without this, only the first would open.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem

```
var window = new Window()
{
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.Hidden,
    Height = 0;
    Width = 0; 
};
window.Show();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).