# Hosting WPF in separate C++ thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, c++-cli, interop

Need to substitute old GUI engine with WPF in a C++ library. I don't have control of the application main (implementing a DLL) meaning I don't control the threading model (In contrast to [Walkthrough: Hosting WPF Content in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744829(v=vs.110).aspx)). Since WPF requires STA I understand I need to launch a separate thread for it like so:

```
Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &ThreadClass::ThreadEntryPoint));
t->SetApartmentState(ApartmentState::STA);
t->Start();

ThreadEntryPoint() {
    App^ app = gcnew App();
    Window^ w = gcnew Window();
    app->Run(w);
}
```

Back in native the old GUI engine does so which is similar to what MFC would do:

```
Create dialog/window d;
d->SomeLabel->Caption = "abc";
d->ComboBox->Add(item);
etc...
d->ShowDialog(); // at which point control passes to user
```

and:

```
DialogClass:OnButtonPress() {
    SomeLabel->Caption = "xyz";
}
```

a. Ideally I would like to be able to use such simple instructions (Control.property = x) for WPF but since it's in a separate thread it's not possible, is it?

b. In order to be able to manipulate GUI controls before the window appears I did Sleep(Infinite) after gcnew Window() but before app->Run(w) and Interupt()ed the main thread. I used this example that gets a property (how to change field value?):

```
Type^ t = w->label1->GetType();
Object^ o = w->label1;
DispatcherObject ^dispObj = (DispatcherObject^)(o);
PropertyInfo ^propertyInfo = t->GetProperty( "Name" );
Object^ result = dispObj->Dispatcher->Invoke(gcnew Func<Object^,array<Object^>^, Object^>(propertyInfo, &PropertyInfo::GetValue), dispObj);
```

which failed amongst other reasons because the WPF thread was in sleep. Of course I can implement a whole Sleep/Interrupt mechanism for each property I set but it seems bad design.

My question, assuming WPF is the way to go, what is the correct way to implement?

Comment: If practical, I would encourage limiting the C++/CLI to an interop dll and writing most of your core WPF logic in a C# dll. It's more challenging to make a subtle mistake that way and it builds _so_ much faster. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge you are having is writing to dependency properties directly. Those can only be done on same thread as the Window they are in.

WPF works better by having its dependency properties read values via bindings - that avoids a lot of the threading issues. What you want is an intermediate layer with one or more classes that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. This is the ViewModel(s) of the MVVM coding pattern. The XAML for your WPF would then use bindings to retreive the values of the properties on the ViewModel, and the ViewModel's changed event would notify the WPF app when to update. If you want to wait until all the properties are set before displaying a window the user, you can set up the ViewModel first then create the WPF app and window (avoiding the thread sleep issue).

WPF is designed to be mostly declarative, using XAML instead of code to set up. If it works better for you to set up the Window with code instead of XAML, you can still follow the same pattern, just do all your setup on the dispatcher thread at once instead of piecemeal. You can set the WPF Window to be hidden, see [Showing a hidden WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994453/showing-a-hidden-wpf-window) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @NextInLine. How do I implement "SomeLabel" or "ComboBox" in the VM without declaring each & every of their properties in the VM? Adding a Control type to the VM will not work.

Comment: The view model would have to declare each property whose content can change. Static properties like text can be declared directly in XAML, as would types like ComboBox. If your ComboBox only displays sometimes, you can toggle its Visibility property from your view model.

Comment: If you need to do everything via code as in your original example, just set the window visibility to collapsed, do all your work (preferably in a as few methods as possibly called by Dispatcher.Invoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke) and set the window visibility to visible at the end.